# Unmask a value coming from API in UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, enums, masking

I am getting masked value as input from C# API code. I need to display buttons depending on this masked value. For example, assume stop button has an enum value of 4 and hold button has an enum value of 5 in c#.
I will get a masked value as response in UI. Something like "45". I need to use this and display stop/hold buttons if the value is present in the response.

Looking for an equivalent Jquery/Javascript code for below snippet:

```
if  (AllowedRequests.HasFlag(RequestType.RequestStop))
   ShowStopButton();
```

Comment: are you using `$.ajax` to make a request ?

Comment: yes. using $.ajax to make a request

Comment: try this .. http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/WQXXT/711/